# Im getting LIMIT[0,25] error while executing the query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

That's what i've tried to wrtie the query

```
select posts.*  ,users.* 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users
   ON posts.user_id = users.id
   WHERE posts.user_id != '27'
   AND posts.pid EXISTS(SELECT post_id FROM favourites WHERE posts.pid=favourites.post_id)
```

and this is the ERROR

```
select posts.*  ,users.* 
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users
   ON posts.user_id = users.id
   WHERE posts.user_id != '27'
   AND posts.pid EXISTS(SELECT post_id FROM favourites WHERE posts.pid=favourites.post_id) LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS(SELECT post_id FROM favourites WHERE posts.pid=favourites.post_id) LIM...' at line 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `IN` not ÈXISTS.

the syntax for exists is different

```
SELECT 
    posts.*, users.*
FROM
    posts
        INNER JOIN
    users ON posts.user_id = users.id
WHERE
    posts.user_id != '27'
        AND posts.pid IN (SELECT 
            post_id
        FROM
            favourites
        WHERE
            posts.pid = favourites.post_id)
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

This will check if there is a favourite witht that posts id

```
SELECT 
    posts.*, users.*
FROM
    posts
        INNER JOIN
    users ON posts.user_id = users.id
WHERE
    posts.user_id != '27'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 
            post_id
        FROM
            favourites
        WHERE
            posts.pid = favourites.post_id)
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

Comment: can you please convert into syntax of EXISTS?

Comment: @sachmotivesure i added it to my answer